# The app reference non-public selectors in Payload: cacheIdentifier, imageContentMode

Tags: xcode6, nimbus

I am using Xcode 6.1. I get following error when try to submit the app. Tried to del derived data but no luck.

iTunes Store operation failed.
The app reference non-public selectors in Payload/Appname.app/Appname: cacheIdentifier, imageContentMode, setImageContentMode:, setImageCropRect:

I suspect its relating to NINetworkImageView of Nimbus library, but have no idea how to fix it.

Any help is much appreciated.

> Update: The App was approved by App Store.

Comment: Hi there - please could you share how you resolved this issue?

Comment: Sorry. I did not solve it. Just submitted it with the warning.